# Laravel not uploading actual files on server

Tags: laravel-filesystem

I recently hosted my first Laravel project. This therefore means that the public folder is on `public_html` while the others are on one forder in the root.

I was uploading a file to the server and got the error `Could not create img/photos directory` (paraphrase). I googled for quite some time and after that i gave 777 permission to `img` and `photos` and the error disappeared. The only thing is that now there is no error being caught but the file is just not being uploaded.

NOTE: In my form declaration i have set `'files'=>true`, i have properly modified my autoload and `paths.php` paths.

```
// controller
            // upload cover photo if any
            $path = public_path().'/img/album-cover-photos';
            if(Input::hasFile('photo'))
            {
                $ext = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $name = "Album-Cover-".$album->id.'-'.date('YmdHis').'.'.$ext;

                Input::file('photo')->move($path,$name);
                $album->cover_photo = $name;
                $album->save();
            }
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: Check this link: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9176

Comment: Nice link. But that is to say that in the `path` variable i should not includethe `public_html()` path?

Comment: yeah... just add `img` path and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer this. I got where the problem was. Even if i insisted in the question that I had set `paths.php` paths correctly, that was exactly where the problem was. `public` path had been set as `__DIR__.'/../public_html/mylaravelpublic` instead of `__DIR__.'/../../public_html/mylaravelpublic`.
I really hope that this helps somebody.

Just to say, im on shared hosting so my laravel public folder contents are put in a `public_html` subfolder as above, and not in `public_html` itself.If you are not on shared hosting, i think your path should just end at `public_html` without any subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = public_path().'/../img/album-cover-photos';
            if(Input::hasFile('photo'))
            {
                $ext = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $name = "Album-Cover-".$album->id.'-'.date('YmdHis').'.'.$ext;

                Input::file('photo')->move($path,$name);
                $album->cover_photo = $name;
                $album->save();
            }`enter code here`
```